# Synchronize content of the collection with another collection

Tags: c#

I want to synchronize the content of the collection (C1) with another collection (C2) this way:

- if the particular item presents in C1, and absents in C2 it must be deleted from C1;
- if the particular item presents in C2, and absents in C1, it must be added to C1;
- if the particular item presents both in C1 and C2, it must be leaved in C1.

The order of items in C1 after the synchronization doesn't matters.

Implementation I wrote looks like this:

```
    public static void Synchronize<T>(this ICollection<T> first, ICollection<T> second, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        // delete items, which present in first, but absent in second
        foreach (var item in first.Except(second, comparer).ToArray())
        {
            first.Remove(item);
        }

        // add items, which present in second, but absent in first
        foreach (var item in second.Except(first, comparer).ToArray())
        {
            first.Add(item);
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering, is there a more elegant or standard way?

**Update.**

Sorry, some clarification.

C1 doesn't have to be a copy of C2, because `T` will be some entity, loaded from database, and I will test equality by identifier (the other data of two entities with the same id may differ). Updated code sample.

Comment: Seems ok to me. You could use LINQ, but that would only be syntactically sugar.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Try this if you just wanted to shorten it.

```
first.Intersect(second, comparer).Union(second, comparer); //Will return an IEnumerable<T>
```

If I'm reading your requirements correctly, you can summarise it as

"C1 should equal the contents C2."

e.g.

- C1 contains 1,2,3
- C2 contains 2,3,4

So

- Remove '1' because it is not in C2
- Leave '2' & '3' present cos they are in C2
- Add '4' because it is present in C2

So all you want to do is replace C1 with a copy of the contents of C2.

```
public static void Synchronize<T>(this ICollection<T> first, ICollection<T> second)
{
    first.Clear();
    foreach(var s in second) { first.Add(s); }
}
```

Comment: `RemoveAll` is a method from `List` and not from `ICollection`

Answer (score -1):

In fact you want to `first` becomes `second`, that what your algorithm does.

So you can do it in a more elegant way like this:

```
first = second.ToList();
```

Comment: That won't work. first and second are ICollections. first could be a System.ObjectModel.Collection and your changing it to a list. In fact I don't think that'll modified collection even come back out of the extension method.

Comment: I agree that is not very suitable to set `first` as a more derived type than `ICollection` (`List` in this case) but as we are working with `ICollections` we are supposed not to care about what type `first` is (as it remains `ICollection`). For the second point I know that that code will not change the reference of `first` inside an extension method (only if it is used as a ref parameter), but I was not talking about using it in an extension method but just using it like that.